# Equivalent definitions of $C^r(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, notation

The question is motivated from the definition of $C^r(\Omega)$ I learned from S.S.Chern's *Lectures on Differential Geometry*:

Suppose $f$ is a real-valued function defined on an open set $\Omega\subset{\bf R}^m$. If all the $k$-th order partial derivatives of $f$ exist and are continuous for $k\leq r$, then we say $f\in C^r(\Omega)$. Here $r$ is some positive integer.

While in Folland's *Introduction to Partial Differential Equations*, $C^r(\Omega)$ denotes the space of functions possessing continuous derivatives up to order $r$ on $\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is an open subset of ${\bf R}^m$ and $k$ is a positive integer.

It's trivial to show that these two definitions are equivalent when $m=1$. So here is my question:

> Are these two definitions equivalent in the higher dimensions? How to prove it?

---

**Edit**: The question was partially answered by Didier [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44355/can-being-differentiable-imply-having-continuous-partial-derivatives/44364#44364). I do not think it is trivial for me. It boils down to the following one:

> In the higher dimension case, say,
>   $f:{\bf R}^n\to {\bf R}$($n\geq 2$), what's
>   the relationship between the higher
>   order partial derivative of $f$ and
>   the high order derivative $f^{(k)}$?

When $1\leq k\leq 2$, $f^{(k)}$ is the [gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) and the [Hessian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) respectively. The answer to the above questions in these two cases is clear. I have no idea for $k>2$. I don't know much about tensor, I'm not sure if the question is related to the topic of multilinear algebra.

Comment: I think something went wrong here. Look at the exponents of your ${\mathbb R}$'s.

Comment: @Christian: Notation corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $r$-th derivative $d^r f(x)$ of a function $f:\ {\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}$ at a point $x\in {\mathbb R}^n$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $r$ in the $n$ variables $X_1$, $\ldots$, $X_n$, where $X$ is a tangent vector "attached to the point $x$". The coefficients of this polynomial are the $r$-th partial derivatives of $f$ at the point $x$, and things are set up such that $x \to d^r f(x)$ is continuous as a "polynomial-valued function" iff all these partial derivatives are continuous. So the two definitions alluded to are actually the same.

In the case $r=1$ this means that $f\in C^1$ iff $\nabla f(x)$ is a continuous vector-valued function of $x$ iff the $n$ partial derivatives ${\partial f\over \partial x_k}$ are continuous.

If $f$ is vector-valued then the above applies to every component $f_i$ of $f$; but of course which enough sophistication  we can forget about coordinates altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44355/can-being-differentiable-imply-having-continuous-partial-derivatives/44364#44364).