# Why is the notation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ used?

Tags: notation, partial-derivative, math-history

I am wondering why the notation $\frac{df}{dx}$ isn't used for partial derivatives, because it seems to me like someone could tell that it was a partial derivative if they knew that $f$ was a function of several variables, so no need to use a different notation.

Comment: This is not backed up by any historical research, but mathematically: $df/dx$ acts like a fraction (say, in the chain rule) but $\partial f/\partial x$ doesn't, so it's nice to have different notations.

Answer (score 2):

As [this](http://jeff560.tripod.com/calculus.html) states,

> The "curly d" was used in 1770 by [Antoine-Nicolas Caritat, Marquis de Condorcet](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/Mathematicians/Condorcet.html) (1743-1794) in "Memoire sur les Equations aux différence partielles," which was published in [Histoire de L'Academie Royale des Sciences, pp. 151-178, Annee M. DCCLXXIII (1773)](http://visualiseur.bnf.fr/Visualiseur?Destination=Gallica&O=NUMM-3568).
>
> > Throughout this paper, both $dz$ & $\partial z$ will either denote two partial differences of $z$, where one of them is with respect to $x$, and the other, with respect to $y$, or $dz$ and $\partial z$ will be employed as symbols of total differential, and of partial difference, respectively.

Caritat wanted to differentiate (if you'll pardon the pun) between the [total differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables) and the partial derivative, which have two completely different meanings (This is elaborated upon in [an answer by Lost](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/656559/170257)). Legendre and Jacobi later used the same $\partial$ for partial derivatives, and the notation stuck.