# An example of differentiable functions with discontinuous partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Let $$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
> (x^2+y^2) \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}),\:\text{if $(x,y) \not= (0,0)$;}\\ 
> 0,\:\text{if  $(x,y)=(0,0)$;} \end{array}\right.$$
>
> Prove that the partial derivatives exist for all $c \in R^2$ but are not continuous in $(0,0)$

My approach:

I have already proved that the partial derivatives exist if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$. and n the case that $(x,y) = (0,0)$:

\begin{align}
\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)&=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f[(0,0)+t(1,0)]-f(0,0)}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f[(t,0)]}{t} \\
&=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{t^2 \sin (1/t)}{t} \\
&=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} {t \sin (1/t)}
\end{align}
and due to $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} t=0$ and $\sin (1/t) \le 1 $ then $=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} {t \sin (1/t)}=0$

In the same way I can prove that $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$

In order to prove that the partial derivatives are not continuous I must prove that $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac {\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) \neq 0$

I'm stuck here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Away from the origin, one can use the standard differentiation formulas to calculate that

[image]

Both of these derivatives oscillate wildly near the origin. For example, the derivative with respect to $x$ along the $x$-axis is

[image]

for $x\neq 0$, where $\operatorname{sign}(x)$ is $\pm1$ depending on the sign of $x$. In this case, the sine term goes to zero near the origin but the cosine term oscillates rapidly between $1$ and $−1$, as it is not multiplied by anything small.

---

This is an example of [differentiable functions with discontinuous partial derivatives](https://mathinsight.org/differentiable_function_discontinuous_partial_derivatives). See the analysis in the nice linked article. And also this old question on the site:

[Can "being differentiable" imply "having continuous partial derivatives"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44355/9464)